# Is it he and [name], or am I still wrong?

Tags: grammar, american-english

I'm writing something for a friend. The sentence I'm trying to write is this: "What Sam didn't understand was that **he and Nick** were more alike than he thought."

Is this right? Or is there a better way to put it instead of "he and Nick"? Thank you!

Comment: I see nothing wrong with it.  There is, of course, always the possibility of confusion as to whom the two instances of "he" refer to, but that's a hazard in many constructions -- generally one relies on context to keep it clear.

Answer (score 1):

**He and Nick** is correct.  I don't believe there's a better way to put it unless you restructure the sentence, but I don't think it's necessary. :)

Comment: It would help if you could cite some sources to justify your statement. I agree with what you've written, but how would anyone know who to believe if I posted the answer that "He and Nick" is totally wrong?